# Reading escape characters with scan()

Tags: r, string

I have looked at the existing questions on this but it didn't help. I am trying to read an SQL query from a text file and it has quotes and a regex in it. I can't find a way to get the a `\'` character from scanning a string. I have tried:

```
> scan(text=" 'H' ", what="character")
Read 1 item
[1] "H"
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> scan(text=" \'H\' ", what="character")
Read 1 item
[1] "H"
> scan(text=" \\'H\\' ", what="character")
Read 1 item
[1] "\\'H\\'"
```

I want the result of my `scan()` to be `\'H\'`, i.e. a string that prints out `'H'` when you call `cat` on it. In other words, what string `x` produces

```
> scan(text=x, what="character")
Read 1 item
[1] "\'H\'"
```

I thought the second example would do this, but it doesn't. Or is there an alternative to `scan()` which doesn't make silent changes to the string it reads in?

(Similarly, for the regex I would like `scan()` to return a string that when `cat`ted produces `'^\\d+'`.)

Comment: What about `scan(text = " 'H' ", what = "", quote = "")`?  This won't print the backslashes but will give the desired `cat()` output

Comment: Deleted answer by @Richard Scriven solved my problem using `scan(text=" 'H' ", what="character", quote="")`. I couldn't work out what `quote` does from the documentation.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure.  Undelete my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your first call to include an adjustment to the `quote` argument.

```
x <- scan(text = " 'H' ", what = "", quote = "")
x
# [1] "'H'"
cat(x)
# 'H'
```

Setting `quote = ""` says that there are no quoting characters, and therefore the quotes are read as-is.